# Como fica a ER para mascarar um código alfanumerico?

Tags: javascript, mask

Preciso mascarar um campo de código alfanumérico de 13 caracteres enquanto o usuário digita, separado por hífen, como por exemplo: 0DF7M3-R34X21

Estou usando uma função para aplicar a máscara, portanto seria aplicada da seguinte forma:

`function mask_code(valor) { valor = valor.replace('ER', '$1-$2'); return valor; }`

Grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o Lib [jQuery-Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

```js
// 0DF7M3-R34X21
$('#test').mask('AAAAAA-AAAAAA');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<label>Teste :</label>
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

Na lib `A` seria combinações que batem com `[a-zA-Z0-9]`